# Watin AttachTo: Timeout while waiting for frame document becoming available

Tags: wpf, internet-explorer, pdf, popup, watin

I am trying to make WatiN attach to an IE popup window (IE 10).
This popup contains a frameset --> a single frame --> a pdf document.
My goal is to save this pdf to my disk.

```
Dim winExists = IE.Exists(Of IE)(Find.ByUrl(Function(url) url.Contains("__ADFvDlg")))
If winExists Then 'this evaluates to true
  Dim win = IE.AttachTo(Of IE)(Find.ByUrl(Function(url) url.Contains("__ADFvDlg"))) ' Timeout while waiting for frame document becoming available
End If
```

1) I have tried using the above code inline or in a STA thread

2) When coded inline, its parent thread is also STA

3) I have tried to increase the default timeout to 8 minutes, same result after 8 minutes have passed

There is no other option for me than to parse this particular popup, since it is a site built with Oracle ADF and, apart from the fact that it is A MESS, it is very strange at times...this popup has a URL that somehow works only once. If I try to use it in another window, no pdf is returned. The same happens when I refresh the popup.

I cannot fetch the PDF in the Temporary Internet Files since it is not there (I suppose this is because the website works under SSL).

Any guidelines or solutions even outside WatiN's scope is more than welcome since I've hit a brick wall.

Technologies: VS2012, WPF

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found it easiest when I tried the same thing by making the pop-up show up as a new tab. That way I could attach to it's URL. From there I would use

```
File.WriteAllText(fileName, responseDownLoad.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
```

Where responseDownload will be a HttpResponseMessage